# Bootstrap + Mithril HTML Table Rendering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mithril.js

I can't get Mithril to render any Bootstrap tables. I have Bootstrap button elements that render just fine using the following (basic) code:

```
 var TableModule = {
      view: function(){
          return [
             m("button.btn btn-lg btn-primary", { onclick: function () { alert("derr"); } }, "Teh Button"),
             m("table.table table-striped",
                  m("tr", [m("td", "herp"), m("td", "derp")]))
          ]
      }
  } 
  m.module(document.getElementById("test4"), TableModule);
```

If I hard code the table using:

```
<table class="table table-striped"><tr><td>herp</td><td>derp</td></tr></table>
```

(which is the exact same html the the Mithril code above produces) I get the following:
[image]

Ideas, thoughts, suggestions? Any and all welcome.

Answer (score 3):

When adding static CSS classes in Mithril, you are encouraged to use the `.` CSS selector syntax, see this [section](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.html#usage).

So your code should be:

```
var TableModule = {
          view: function(){
              return [
                 m("button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary", { onclick: function () { alert("derr"); } }, "Teh Button"),
                 m("table.table.table-striped",
                      m("tr", [m("td", "herp"), m("td", "derp")]))
              ]
          }
      }

m.mount(document.getElementById("test4"), TableModule);
```

The other comments from @ciscoheat is also valid. You should use `m.mount` or `m.route` in the newer versions of Mithril.

Answer (score 2):

It could be so simple that you need to call `m.mount` instead of `m.module`. Modules is a pre-0.2 concept as well, components is what's being used right now. (Not that big difference, but worth reading about: http://mithril.js.org/mithril.component.html)

**Edit:** Try adding dots between classes in the `m` calls as well. `button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the TRs in TBODY. This seems to be done by Bootstrap automagically, but not when using v-nodes and m-helper.